# Generate report where each character comes in a box

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, rdlc

My report needs to display all information of application form in box format - similar to a bank account opening form:

```
|M|A|R|K| |J|O|H|A|N|S|O|N
```

How can I achieve this in Crystal Reports?

Comment: What is the maximum number of boxes you'd want to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the some alternate solution as crystal report not providing what I want. I have find the monospace fonts which have already bordered with particular character. By this technique I am able to fulfill my goal.

Thanks all for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

The logic for splitting the name may differ, but for simplicity I used an array extension method:

```
string name = "MARK JOHANSON";    
char[] nameArray = name.ToArray<char>();

{nameArray[0]} &"|"& {nameArray[1]} &"|"& {nameArray[2]} & ..
```

Comment: actually I need top and bottom border also so each character fit to box

Answer (score 0):

This is very uncommon, so Crystal doesn't have something out of the box that supports this feature. When push comes to shove, if you don't like [user3350003's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790354/generate-report-where-each-character-comes-in-a-box/39791028#39791028), you'll probably have to make a series of box objects for each letter. In this case, Formulas.

Assume you're willing to support names up to N characters total. Create N many Formula Fields named Box1, Box2, Box3... BoxN. The logic inside each will be very similar - For example, Box7 would look like:

```
MID({PersonName}, 7, 1)
```

Then arrange them in order on your report, turn off Can Grow, and format them with Outside Borders:

[image]